# Can ice ever sink in the water?

Tags: water, phase-transition, density, liquid-state

It is generally taught in schools that ice is less dense than water, which is why ice is seen to float on the water. But isn't ice heavier compared to water at a temperature quite above 4 degrees celsius[See the density plot in the image below]?

What happens when I put an ice cube into a glass of water at room temperature? Won't that ice sink?

If not, what am I missing? If yes, why isn't that mentioned clearly in textbooks?

[image]

- Image credit: By Klaus-Dieter Keller, created with QtiPlot, Font: Liberation Sans - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=19093965

Comment: What happens? Do the experiment!

Comment: No. Water expands when it freezes, so its density is less than liquid water. I don't get your second sentence "But isn't ice lighter compared to water at a temperature quite above 4 degrees celsius". Yes, it is still less dense, and it still floats.

Comment: "*But isn't ice lighter compared to water at a temperature quite above 4 degrees celsius*" Yes, as shown in the plot. Why, then, would it sink? Please proofread your question in case a typo has changed your intended meaning.

Comment: Oops! Should be "heavier". I have edited and corrected.

Comment: Isn't your question inconsistent with the plot you provide?  The heaviest ice (about 935 kg/m^3 at -150°C) is less dense than the lightest liquid water (about 958 kg/m^3 at 100°C).

Comment: @DavidBailey That's true. I perhaps focused on the inset plot and thought the 0 degrees density value is for the ice. But the mystery still remains to me: Why's there a density after the transition? I used to think that H-bond starts forming at 4 degrees Celsius and below. What happens physically?

Answer (score 4):

Water density (in the temperature range 0-100 C over which it is normally liquid) varies within the approximate range 960-1000 kg/m^3 (as shown in the graph you included with your post). Ice density (in the temperature range -273-0 C) varies within the approximate range 915-940 kg/m^3. So ice at *any* temperature below 0 C, will be less dense (i.e. lighter) than any *equal* volume of water at atmospheric pressure, and will therefore float.

If you heat water under pressure it will stay liquid to higher temperatures. Water has a volumetric thermal expansion coefficient of approximately 2.1x10^-4 (i.e. it becomes less dense as it gets hotter), so if you heat it to a temperature of approximately 251 C in a pressure cooker (at which point it will be somewhere around 45 atmospheres so you need a really thick-walled pressure cooker), and then drop in a piece of ice which has been cooled to around -90 C (you need to add the ice without removing the lid of the pressure cooker of course), then the ice ***will*** sink in the water (until it melts, or heats up a bit).

Alternately, if you take normally cool ice-cubes from your freezer (-5 to -10 C about), and put them into some room temperature 100 proof whiskey then the cubes will sink. Proving ice doesn't always float in water of life (*Uisge Beath*).